# True/False Question on subspace topology.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider $X=(1,2018]\cup\{\frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Let $ (X,d)$ be the usual metric space. Which of the following option are true?

(1) $  (1,2018]  $ is an open set.

(2) $(1,2018]$ is not an open set

(3) $\{\frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an open set.

(4) $0$ is not a limit point of the. $\{\frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

My efforts.

(1) True. Take intersection of X with (1,2019)

(2) False

(3) False as if I take a open ball of radius $0.01$ around say $0.5$ it is not properly contained in the set.

(4) $0$ is a limit point of X. It juts shows that space is not complete. So this is also False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) in fact $(1,2018]$ is a clopen (closed and open) set because $$\forall x\in (1,2018],\exists\epsilon>0,\{y\in X|d(x,y)<\epsilon\}\subseteq (1,2018]$$(2) answered as before

(3) it is not neither open nor closed. No neighborhood of $1$ is included by $\{\dfrac{1}{n}|n\in\Bbb N\}$ (**while for any other point the exists some neighborhood contained by the set**). Also take the sequence $a_n=\dfrac{1}{n}$ which is convergent to $0$ but $0\notin \{\dfrac{1}{n}|n\in\Bbb N\}$.

(4) $0$ is not a limit point; adding it to the set makes it closed, however it doesn't belong to $X$. You can observe this fact graphically over real line.